# shuffle string with javascript and keep track of the number

Tags: javascript, string, random, shuffle

I have a function

```
function shuffle(length,string) {
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = string;
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
       result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return result;
}
```

and I use it like to generate the array of the random string

```
var value = shuffle(66,'guitar'); value.split('')
```

Now I am using this function in a setinterval function to generate the random string every 5 seconds But I need to keep track of the characters so if the first characters was moved to fifth position I need to know.

so the output of the shuffle function should be

```
array('g,5','i,4','t,1')
```

Numbers after comma denoted the new place of the characters with respect to the index of the array.First position was moved to fifth and second position was moved to fourth position and so on.

Comment: result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
 Should denote the result

Comment: What is the length argument for?

Comment: length is there to generate that characters of strings so the random string generated will have a length of 66.

Comment: But your `shuffle` doesn't really shuffle, it generates a random string with the `string` input used as character pool. There is no guarantee, that every character gets used. In case of `shuffle(1, "ggg")`, is it really important, which "g" was used?

Comment: you are right @ASDFGerte do you have a better suggestion or function to generate random string of a given length and which can keep track of each characters.

Comment: So essentially you want to create an array of a specified length in the format `character, original index` from the provided string. Does it matter if all the characters in the input string don't appear in the output?

Comment: I don't understand the goal you are trying to achieve, therefore, no. What you are describing surely is possible, but i just have the feeling, that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You could just shuffle an array of offsets and then loop through the array printing characters at those offsets from the unaltered string.

Comment: Could you provide a sample input and output. e.g. would this be a correct output? 
 
`shuffle(66, 'guitar')` -> `[ 'i,2', 't,3', 'r,5', 'a,4', 'g,0', 'u,1' ]`

Comment: @poojan the output should be an array of 66 length and two parameters one character from the string and second parameter showing the place where this character previous position so if the character which was in first position moved to 15 the 14th index of array will be [g,15]